# How to use the file path as the source parameter from os.walk to copy files

Tags: python, parameters, path

Okay, so I'm not sure how to get python to use the path to a file that it found through an os.walk function as the `source` parameter for the `shutil.copy(source, destination)` arguments.

My code example is this

```
for folderName, subfolders, filenames in os.walk('/Users/me/Documents'):
    print('The current folder is '+folderName)
    for subfolder in subfolders:
        print('SUBFOLDER OF '+folderName+": "+subfolder)
    for filename in filenames:
        print("FILE INSIDE "+folderName+": "+filename)
        if filename.endswith('.txt'):
            os.chdir(filename)
            shutil.copy(filename, '/Users/me/Documents/School/IT 145/Text Files')
    print("")
```

If the file has a .txt extension, I would like python to copy that file to the specified folder.

My error message I get is this

```
The current folder is /Users/me/Documents/Text Files
FILE INSIDE /Users/me/Documents/Text Files: guest.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/Documents/School/IT 145/Programming Work/os_walk.py", line 16, in <module>
    os.chdir(filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'guest.txt'
```

From what I understand, python is going back to the current working directory to do the shutil.copy, but I don't understand why if I pass it the file path that it just found it won't use that as the source path for the file to copy.

This is my first ever python programming class, and really my first brush with python all, so any teaching thoughts would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current code *never* leaves its original working directory. You can verify this by running:

```
print(os.getcwd())
```

Your `os.walk()` does **not** change the current directory (CWD).

Your attempt at changing the CWD:

```
os.chdir(filename)
```

does not work since `filename` is a file name and not a directory.

```
os.chdir(folderName)
```

would work.

You *could* use the approach of changing into the directory just to copy the file. But, you can't be doing that it every iteration of your loop, either -- only on the first. Or, better yet, you could change into the directory at the *start*. **In any case, I advice against this approach since its an unnecessary overhead.**

Instead, just prefix the `filename` with its parent directory -- i.e. `folderName` when you call `shutil.copy()`.

For example:

```
shutil.copy(os.path.join(folderName, filename), '/Users/me/Documents/School/IT 145/Text Files')
```

*Side note for readability:*
Put `'/Users/me/Documents'` and `'/Users/me/Documents/School/IT 145/Text Files'` into named variables -- which makes it easier to read, change and/or reuse if needed.

*Side note for portability:*
Aim to use `os.path.join()` instead of using `/` for the directory separator.